# AngularJS $location not updated properly when using $routeProvider

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-routing

I have an Angular JS application with a `defaultController` which controls the header of the app. Then I have some other controllers one for each view. The views are loaded in the `<main>`. I load the views using the `$routeProvider` with this code:

```
myapp.config(['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/login', {
                templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
                controller: 'loginController'
            }).
            when('/dashboard', {
                templateUrl: 'templates/dashboard.html',
                controller: 'dashboardController'
            }).
            ...
```

I am trying to display a LOGOUT button inside the header when the loaded view is the dashboard and hide it if the loaded view is the login view. In order to do that I have on the `defaultController` the `$location` object and I properly add and remove classes from the LOGOUT button with `ng-class`.

There is only one problem: $location gives me the correct path the first time I load the page, but after I change the view (changed by the `$routeProvider`) that variable is not updated anymore, so when I am actually on `/#/dashboard` , the `$location.url` is still on `/login`. Here the controller code:

```
controllers.controller('defaultController', ['$scope', 'ipCookie', '$location', function($scope, ipCookie, $location) {
    $scope.url = $location.url();
    ...
```

I also tried with `$window.location.hash` with the same result.

Any idea?

EDIT: after the accepted answer this is what I ve added on the `defaultController` in order to make it work

```
$scope.$on("$locationChangeSuccess", function() {
        $scope.url = $location.url();      
    });
```

Comment: try just location.hash and import $location where you use this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The location is probably updated in the service after your default controller is loaded.

You can either inject the `$location` service into the scope and make decisions in your template based on it (then it will automatically be watched and re-evaluated) or you could listen for the `$locationChangeSuccess` event.

When injecting, you can simply `$scope.location = $location` and then use something like `<a ng-hide="location.path() != '/something'">`.

`$location` broadcasts the `$locationChangeSuccess` on the root scope, so you should be able to listen for it on whichever scope you have available: `$scope.$on( "$locationChangeSuccess", function() { /* do something */ } );`

Comment: if $location is updated after, I need the `dashboardController` to notify the `defaultController` somehow about the new `$location`?

Comment: @MirkoGuarnier: You can use the same principles in any controller. You don't need to have one controller notify the other.

Comment: But how do I update the logout button which stays outside the scope of the controller which knows the correct `$location` ?

Comment: @MirkoGuarnier What's wrong with the examples I gave you?

Comment: Sorry now I understood. 
I will accept the answer and update my question with the final code
Notice that the method is not `$scope.on` but `$scope.$on`